# Object Property name mangled in obfuscated js and unable to retrieve it

Tags: javascript

I do

```
return {
  messageId: payload['messageId'],
  data: payload['data'],
  result: payload['result']
};
```

and later try to retrieve it using obj['messageId'].
It works in deobfuscated js but in obfuscated js, the messageId key name gets manged into 'Fe' while the other two remain the same. My code fails trying to find obj['messageId'].

Is this wrong way of coding, and should I do

```
return {
  'messageId': payload['messageId'],
   . . .
```

?

Comment: What tool is doing that? There are lots of code obfuscation/compression tools.

Comment: When you access the property eventually, you should be using `ob.messageId`, not `obj['messageId']`. Minifiers usually ignore property access via string literals. Please post the code where you access the object and also which minifier you are using.

Comment: I don't know all that. It is all buried inside proprietary tools at my work. So is it always safe to access using dot notation then? Dot notation however doesn't work on untyped objects, only on typedefed objects.

Comment: Are you saying that the minifier you are using is some internal tool?

Comment: No, I can't find it, it is buried inside our build tools owned by a different team.  It is with Google closure compiler. Just tell me a way to code so that it works. Will return {
  'messageId': payload['messageId'], not prevent the problem? I can't verify because on local workstation the js is always deobfuscated.